# How to force slick to generate ddl for inherited columns

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I have a situation whereby a number of my tables will all require the same columns:

- id:Long
- created:Timestamp

The "created" column however is never used by the web, "id" is.

To do this I've used an abstract class and object:

```
abstract class BaseObject{ 
    val id:Option[Long]
}

abstract class BaseTable[T <: BaseObject](tableName: String) extends Table[T](None, tableName) {
 def this() {
    this("BaseTable")
  }

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def created = column[Timestamp]("created",O.NotNull)

  def autoInc = * returning id
}
```

I then implemented a concrete Client:

```
case class Client(id: Option[Long] = None, name: String = "", contact: String = "", phone: String = "", email: String = "") extends BaseObject
object Clients extends BaseTable[Client]("CLIENT") {
  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)

  def contact = column[String]("contact")

  def phone = column[String]("phone")

  def email = column[String]("email")

  def * = id.? ~ name ~ contact ~ phone ~ email <>(Client.apply _, Client.unapply _)
}
```

And then here's part of the ClientController:

```
object ClientController extends Controller {
 val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> optional(longNumber),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "contact" -> text,
      "phone" -> text,
      "email" -> text
    )(Client.apply)(Client.unapply)
  )
}
```

Now the thing is, I don't ever want the 'created' column returned to the web which is why it's not included in the Client case class, the default projection or the controller form.  I just want to set it on creation, so what I've done is:

```
def doUpdate(client: Client)(implicit s: Session): Client = {
    if (client.id.isDefined) {
      Clients.where(_.id === obj.id).update(client)
    } else {
      Clients.autoInc.insert(obj)
      Clients.where(_.id === updated.get).map(_.created).update(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    }
   client
  }
```

My problem is the slick will not generate the 'created'

column for any of the tables that extend BaseTable. If i add the 'created' column manually everything works fine. Is there a way to still use slick ddl generation and accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention all of them in `def *` or override `def create_*`. I suggest you add it to `def *` and write another `def forWeb` with fewer columns that you map to the case class. Using `clients.map(_.forWeb)` you can get those columns in a query. You can also write `clients.map(_.forWeb).update( ... )`

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at overriding def create_* but ran into some problems when attempting it. I will try the providing a web projection instead.

Comment: Question: if I have to provide a default def * for each table class which in turn must map to the same type as the table (ie: Client) does this not imply that I will have to create two case classes for each table (a complete one to match the def * projection and another to match the forWeb version)?

Comment: You don't have to provide any case class at all. When you leave out the <> mapping, you get a tuple. If you leave it out for * you need to pass a tuple as type argument to Table.